# rpm spec file with 'cat' problem

Tags: bash, rpm

Im writing spec file in which i want to place script to run process from init.d directory. Here it is a part of SPEC file:

```
%prep   

%{__cat} <<EOF  > myapp.run


prog="IMG APP BACKEND"
exec=%{APP_prefix}/bin/myapp.%{_APP}
config=%{APP_prefix}/etc/myapp%{_APP}.xml                                  

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions                                                  

start() {
        if [ $UID -ne 0 || $UID -ne 80 ]; then
                echo "User has insufficient privilege."                       
                exit 4                                                        
        fi
        [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
        [ -f $config ] || exit 6
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon $exec $config && success || failure                            
        retval=$?                                                             
        echo
        [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile                                  
        return $retval                                                        
}
```

when i open myapp.run i get (same part):

```
start() {
        if [ 1031 -ne 0 || 1031 -ne 80 ]; then
                echo "User has insufficient privilege." 
                exit 4
        fi
        [ -x  ] || exit 5
        [ -f  ] || exit 6
        echo -n $"Starting : "
        daemon   && success || failure
        retval=0
        echo
        [  -eq 0 ] && touch
        return
}
```

What im doing wrong ? Why variable UID gets 1031 and so on ?

thx for all answers

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) with `<<EOF`. In the 'sh'/bash shells, (as with most other programming languages) variables inside a heredoc are expanded at run time, the same way as within double-quoted strings. For example, `$UID` is expanded to the user ID of whoever runs the spec file, and `$exec` is expanded to an empty string because it hasn't been set yet.

```
$ cat <<EOF
> I am $USER
> EOF
I am grawity
```

To avoid this, put the limit string in single quotes: **`<<'EOF'`**

```
$ cat <<'EOF'
> I am $USER
> EOF
I am $USER
```